# javafx error in MediaPlayer constructor IllegalStateException

Tags: java, media-player, javafx, illegalstateexception

I have a pretty simple code that I got from this site (courtesy of [senderle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577088/senderle)) to play an mp3 file (I am new with `javafx`)

```
import javafx.scene.media.*;
public class Start
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String bip = "file:/Sounds/sound.mp3";
        Media hit = new Media(bip);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit); // This is line 8 from the Exception
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

when I run this code, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:150)
    at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:52)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:450)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:365)
    at Start.main(Start.java:8)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your media in one of:

1. A JavaFX [Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html)
2. A Swing [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html)
3. A SWT [FXCanvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas.html)

Any of the above options will ensure that the JavaFX toolkit is appropriately initialized before you start to use components that depend on it.